# Can i use getStaticPaths with getInitialProps instead of getStaticProps in NextJs?

Tags: next.js

Can i use getStaticPaths with getInitialProps instead of getStaticProps in NextJs ?

```
export async function getStaticPaths(){
  ...
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
}

Post.getInitialProps = async ({ params = {} } = {}) => {
  const { post } = await getPostBySlug(params?.slug);
  ...
}
```

Comment: what do you need ?

Comment: i figure out i have access to {query} in getInitialProps and i use it the problem is when i export with next export to generate static files i face this problem with the dynamic routes *********** 



encountered errors on following paths:
        /[slug]
        /categories/[slug]
        /posts/[slug]

Comment: i need a solution when i export my project i get all new data without next start

Comment: No, you cannot use `getInitialProps` with `getStaticPaths`, you have to use `getStaticProps`. `getStaticPaths` defines the paths that you want to statically generate, you'll be able to access the dynamic route params by using `params` inside `getStaticProps`, e.g. `params.slug`.